# unable to use getString for a textView - android

Tags: java, android

I am having an issue with a OnRestoreInstanceState for a string within a TextView. This string is basically an arrow (<<) which points to see whose turn it is in the game.

Basically this is my code below:

```
private TextView textViewPlayerOneTurn;

...

    private void switchPlayerTurn(){
        if (playerOneMove){
            textViewPlayerOneTurn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textViewPlayerTwoTurn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else{
            textViewPlayerOneTurn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            textViewPlayerTwoTurn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

...

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putString("textViewPlayerOneTurn", textViewPlayerOneTurn.toString());
        outState.putString("textViewPlayerTwoTurn", textViewPlayerTwoTurn.toString());
        outState.putBoolean("playerOneMove", playerOneMove);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        playerOneMove = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("playerOneMove");
    }
```

What my issue is, is that when I rotate the screen, the pointer always defaults to player one's turn. I may be barking up the wrong tree but my thought would be the onRestoreInstanceState so I wanted to include the following in that method:

textViewPlayerOneTurn = savedInstanceState.getString("textViewPlayerOneTurn");
    textViewPlayerTwoTurn = savedInstanceState.getString("textViewPlayerTwoTurn");

But it gives me error stating it requires **android.widget.TextView** and it found **Java.lang.String**

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`textViewPlayerOneTurn.toString()` returns the string representation of the TextView object which is defined in `toString()` method for TextView class.

`textViewPlayerOneTurn.getText().toString()` will return expected String displayed on `TextView`.

Instead of `textViewPlayerOneTurn.toString()` use `textViewPlayerOneTurn.getText().toString()`

Comment: Ah cool, thanks Sagar. I don't know if you had a look at my other comment on the previous question you dealt with in regards to the test colour changing on rotation. No error now but still does not retain the colour

Answer (score 0):

please use

```
textViewPlayerOneTurn.getText().toString()
```

instead of

```
textViewPlayerOneTurn.toString().
```